# Watson conversaton with Visual Recognition

Tags: watson, watson-conversation

Im working on a project that involves facial expressions, my question is, is it possible to use Watson conversation to guide the conversation based on the facial expression ie: sad, happy, angry.
For example if your expression is sad, watson conversation must lead the convo to make you feel better etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible - you can make Watson conversation follow any logic which you define in your application (including the scenario with emotions) by means of using context variables.

(see more under: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#building-a-client-application)

**The high level idea is**:

- your application is attached to a service which provides current emotion of the user
- when interacting with Watson the application puts this emotion as a variable into context of the conversation.
- you use this variable in conditions of dialog nodes in order to control where the conversation goes depending of the user mood

More specific implementation details will vary depending on how/when you fetch user emotions.